# Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(...)' for class '__lldb_expr_1.B'

Tags: swift, initialization

I'm currently facing a crash regarding the initializers of a class and its subclass. I'm on Swift 5, using Xcode 10.2.1. The app compiles just fine. I was able to isolate the issue in a playground. So, the following code is crashing when creating an instance of `B`.

```
class A {
    private let i: Int

    private init(i: Int) {
        self.i = i
    }
}

extension A {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(i: 0)
    }
}

class B: A { }

B()
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

`MyPlayground.playground: 15: 7: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(i:)' for class '__lldb_expr_1.B'`

We recently upgraded our app to Swift 5, and I don't think it was crashing on Swift 4.2, so maybe this is a new issue in Swift 5? Does anyone know what's causing it? Why isn't the compiler detecting this?

Comment: Removing private from the init method makes the code work. Something with the access level is preventing the convenience init to fail. I'd maybe file a bug at Swift.org, it seems like it *should* work

Comment: That code compiles without errors in a Xcode 10.2.1 command line project, so it might be a Playground issue.

Comment: @NateBirkholz you're right. I'll file a bug.

Comment: @MartinR the code also compiles without errors in the playground, but it crashes during runtime.

Comment: @alex.magellan: Confirmed, it crashes at runtime, but also in a Xcode 10.1 (Swift 4.2) project. Thinking about it again, it is probably *not* a bug: When `B()` is initialized, `self.init(i: 0)` calls `B.init(i: 0)`, but that is not accessible from the subclass because it is `private` to class `A`.

Comment: @MartinR I agree, the extension is allowing me to call a private init. But if that is not allowed, I think I should get a compile-time error, instead of crashing the app at run-time. I filed a bug at bugs.swift.org, as suggested above. It's SR-10965.