# Could not cast value of type 'A' to 'B'

Tags: ios, swift

So I was trying to work around the issue I described in another question ([Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(...)' for class '__lldb_expr_1.B'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56657432/1614222)), but then I faced another issue.

I've created a test project to isolate the issue. I have an `A.swift` file with the following content:

```
class A {
    private let i: Int

    private init(i: Int) {
        self.i = i
    }
}

extension A {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(i: 0)
    }
}
```

And then **in another file** I declare `B` as a subclass of `A`.

```
class B: A { }
```

In order to test this, I have a simple `ViewController` like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let b: B = B()
        let a: A = b

        _ = a as! B
    }

}
```

This compiles just fine, but when I run it, it crashes while downcasting `a` as `B`. This is the error I get:

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyTestProject.A' (0x1070bd570) to 
'MyTestProject.B' (0x1070bd4d8).
```

Edit:
I only get this error if I declare A and B in separate files. If they're declared in the same file, I get the error described at [Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(...)' for class '__lldb_expr_1.B'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56657432/1614222).

Comment: This is in a playground, right?

Comment: @Alexander, no, I created an Xcode project with just a single view controller.

Comment: @Alexander how does one compile but not run in a playground?

Comment: @alex.magellan Hmm, nevermind.

Comment: @matt What do you mean? The reason I was asking was because I was  a little surprised that the class was named `__lldb_expr_1.B`. I would have expected a real module name instead of `__lldb_expr_1`.

Comment: @Alexander you're right. The issue described in my other question was really found in a playground. It happens in the app I'm working on, but I was able to isolate the issue in a playground. For the issue described in this question, I used a small Xcode project as I can only reproduce the issue defining the classes in different files.

Comment: OK I can reproduce in Xcode 11 beta 2.

Comment: @Alexander I don't mean anything. I just don't know how to compile without running in a playground. If there's a way, I wish you'd just tell me what it is. In a real project you can say Build or Build-and-Run but I don't see that choice in a playground.

Comment: @matt I don't know of a way to compile without running in a playground, either. I'm just confused as to what made you ask that, I don't think I implied anything relating to that.

Comment: @Alexander Yes. The OP said “This compiles just fine, but when I run it...”. You said “This is in a playground”. I’m trying to square those.

Comment: @matt Ah. I didn't pick up on that detail. I interpreted that as him trying to express that he had a runtime error (rather than a compile time error). I didn't pick up that he explicitly states the compile and run steps as two separate steps

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a bug. Deciding *what* the bug is, is not so easy.

As my test, I've modified your example slightly. In this file, we have:

```
class A {
    private let i: Int
    private init(i: Int) {
        self.i = i
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(i: 0)
    }
}
```

And in our `viewDidLoad`:

```
let a: A = B()
print(type(of:a))
```

That keeps things nice and simple. Okay, so in another file we have

```
class B : A {}
```

Well then, in my tests:

- In a Release build, we crash: "Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(i:)' for class 'B'" (I'm sure you recognize that one)
- In a Debug build, we don't crash, but we print A, which is clearly the wrong answer.

I could add complications (I tried a lot of things), but I'll add this observation: all problems go away if we delete the word `private` before `init`. With that one change, we print B and we don't crash, in Debug or Release.

So I'm going to theorize that the problem has something to do with the way the initializer inheritance rules are implemented under the hood. They seem to have the power to break polymorphism under certain conditions. (My tests used Xcode 11 beta 2, and thus Swift 5.1.)

Comment: Let me know if you want to file this. If you do, I suggest using my rewrite, as it eliminates some unnecessary dross.